# jBoss Business Central Error Message when Opening Assets

Tags: jboss, drools

To all

When trying to open an asset (DRL or Legency Test), I receive the message "Unable to complete your request. **The following exception occurred: name is empty.**"

I can't find any hint what this means. My rules import from different projects which all can be accessed.

Does anybody have an idea what this could mean? Thank you very much already in advance.

big hug

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I found out by myself. The external data objects configuration had an empty entry. So be careful when adding an external data object - you are able to add an empty row and Business Central let's you save this ... with the empty row causing the error described.

happy coding

Michael Lutz

Comment: Please consider to create a bug report for this issue (or even provide a PR with a fix) so it can be properly addressed.